# How to 'squash' base image layers into a single layer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to upgrade the base image version in one of my images, but due to a layer limit of 40, my builds are failing.

I noticed that in the older image, `docker history` gave this output:

```bash
IMAGE          CREATED        CREATED BY                      SIZE      
092c6c14cf83   8 days ago     /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG     0B        
376101232840   8 days ago     /bin/sh -c /tmp/tmp.sh         65.4MB    
6c58dda60477   8 days ago     /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:a   1.27kB    
1264065f6ae8   7 months ago                                   4.72kB    
<missing>      7 months ago                                   207MB
```

But after updating the image version, this is the output:

```bash
IMAGE          CREATED        CREATED BY                       SIZE     
3233036cf707   41 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)                0B        
1e72b109fe29   41 hours ago   /bin/sh -c /tmp/tmp.sh           65.5MB    
e4bb0f8240aa   41 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:a    1.27kB    
dea12a7906f5   12 days ago    /bin/sh -c rm -f /tmp/tls-ca-    207MB     
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c rm -f '/etc/yum.re'    0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL "dist    0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:7     0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:ad    0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL relea    0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /var/log     0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/log/      0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin     0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV PATH /     0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV contain    0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL io.      0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL io.      0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL io.      0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL des      0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL sum      0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL com      0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL com      0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL          0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD multi:3    0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:21    0B        
<missing>      12 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:09    0B
```

Any clue why this may be happening? These extra layers that are being added seem to come from the base image. Any clue how to make them appear as a single layer like shown in the older build?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized a couple of things regarding this question at a later point of time.

First off, `docker history` does not give you the true layer count*. To find the true layer count, I used `docker inspect --format='{{join .RootFS.Layers "\n"}} $INSTANCE_ID | wc -l` to get the number of true layers.

Secondly, if you still need to squash layers, explore using the `--squash` directive in docker build (experimental feature), or use [`docker-squash`](https://github.com/goldmann/docker-squash).

** - The output of `docker history` shows the list of hashes mapped to the diff of layers. Since these hashes are randomly generated, the mapping is handled by the docker engine. When an image is pulled, this mapping is lost and you get the `<missing>` value in the `IMAGE` field. Couldn't have figured this out without [this amazing blog post](https://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/)*